# How to make a cross-reference to a figure?

Tags: python, python-docx

How to make a cross-reference to a figure caption? The desired output is: *Something useful is shown in Figure 1*. How to get created bookmark reference? Python code I have right now is:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.oxml.shared import OxmlElement, qn
import docx
from lxml.etree import SubElement

def _add_number_range(run, name):
    fldChar = OxmlElement('w:fldChar') 
    fldChar.set(qn('w:fldCharType'), 'begin')
    instrText = OxmlElement('w:instrText')
    instrText.set(qn('xml:space'), 'preserve')
    instrText.text = 'SEQ %s \* ARABIC' % name
    
    fldChar2 = OxmlElement('w:fldChar')
    fldChar2.set(qn('w:fldCharType'), 'separate')
    fldChar3 = OxmlElement('w:t')
    fldChar3.text = "Right-click to update field."
    fldChar2.append(fldChar3)
    
    fldChar4 = OxmlElement('w:fldChar')
    fldChar4.set(qn('w:fldCharType'), 'end')
    
    r_element = run._r
    r_element.append(fldChar)
    r_element.append(instrText)
    r_element.append(fldChar2)
    r_element.append(fldChar4)

document = Document()

#figure cross reference
c = document.add_paragraph('Figure ', style='Caption')
run = c.add_run()
_add_number_range(run, "Figure")
#figure cross reference

c.add_run(': something to show')
    
document.add_page_break()
d = document.add_paragraph('Figure ', style='Normal')
d.add_run('Something useful is shown in ')
#_add_figure_reference

document.save('cr_to_fig.docx')
```

Comment: My best recommendation: create figures in python, create documents in LaTeX.